# Inverted zone in moment.timezone

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs

I am using nodejs and recently started using moment.timezone to get the timezone offset. I have the following code:

```
console.log(moment.tz(new Date(), 'Europe/Athens').zone()); // Prints -120
```

The timezone for 'Europe/Athens' is GMT+2 so i would expect getting '120' and not '-120' and thats what other timezone libraries do.

This issue caused me a serious head scratching bug. It was really easy to fix it once found the problem by just inverting the timezone offset.

Is this a bug on the specific library, or is there a different way to think of zones and offsets? Is there a standard about zone offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `zone()` returns the offset to UTC relative to the selected timezone.

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/how-to/mutator/

Comment: It makes sense, though this is not documented at all. Is anyone else using this notation?

Comment: This is the convention for JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Not at all: "returns the time-zone offset from UTC, in minutes, for the current locale".

Comment: It also explains in there what it means if the number is negative. In the example, they show that `UTC+10` (Austria Eastern Standard Time) is `-600`.

Comment: See also: [Why does JavaScript Date.getTimezoneOffset() consider “-05:00” as a positive offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21102435/634824)