# Javascript converting Date to UTC (And leave unmodified if is already UTC)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

First thing off, I know how to convert the a local date to UTC in Javascript. This isn't a duplicate of that.

I've been trying to get a function that will convert a date to UTC if it isn't already, I don't have control whether or not the input is UTC or not. I can't use Javascript plugins.

Normal solutions would be just to parse a local date into UTC, but parsing a date that's already UTC that way **outputs the weird behavior of modifying the already UTC date incorrectly**.

I have an example function below.

```
function temp() {
  var utc = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 10, 10, 10, 0));
  var local = new Date(2017, 1, 10, 10, 10, 0);

  var utc2 = new Date(utc.getUTCFullYear(), utc.getUTCMonth(), utc.getUTCDate(),  utc.getUTCHours(), utc.getUTCMinutes(), utc.getUTCSeconds());
  var local2 = new Date(local.getUTCFullYear(), local.getUTCMonth(), local.getUTCDate(),  local.getUTCHours(), local.getUTCMinutes(), local.getUTCSeconds());

  var utc3 = new Date(utc.getTime() + utc.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
  var local3 = new Date(local.getTime() + local.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

  Logger.log("Timezone offset: UTC=" + utc.getTimezoneOffset() + " Local=" + local.getTimezoneOffset());
  Logger.log("UTC: " + utc.getTime() + " -> UTC2(" + utc2.getTime() + ") or UTC3(" + utc3.getTime() +")");
  Logger.log("Local: " + local.getTime() + " -> UTC2(" + local2.getTime() + ") or UTC3(" + local3.getTime() +")");
}
```

returns

```
Timezone offset: UTC=420 Local=420
UTC: 1486721400000 -> UTC2(1486746600000) or UTC3(1486746600000)
Local: 1486746600000 -> UTC2(1486771800000) or UTC3(1486771800000)
```

Note that even the UTC date has a timezone offset. And that both methods of converting a local date to UTC strangly modifies the already UTC date to something incorrect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When talking about an ECMAScript Date object, the phrase "*I know how to convert the a local date to UTC in Javascript*" doesn't make sense. Javascript Dates are **always** UTC, they can't be "converted to UTC". If you have a string that you wish to parse, that's another story. However, there is no parsing in your question.

Comment: "*…even the UTC date has a timezone offset*". Dates don't have a timezone offset. The *getTimezoneOffset* method gets the offset from the host system, it has nothing to do with the Date instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing weird about the behavior and unfortunately there is no answer to your question (using the default JavaScript `Date` implementation).

In JavaScript, each `Date` is represented by the milliseconds since the epoch. A `Date` instance is always handled within the interpreters (e.g., your browser's) timezone. Thus, when you call `new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 10, 10, 10, 0));`, you actually create a `Date` instance, which is internally represented by `1486721400000`.

The `getTimezoneOffset()` method always returns values from the perspective of your current timezone. So in my case (California), the following:

```
document.write(new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 8, 10, 0, 0)).toString());
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 8, 8, 10, 0, 0)).toString());
```

outputs (with comments)

```
480 // Wed Feb 08 2017 02:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
420 // Thu Sep 08 2016 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

**Trying to find an answer for your question**

The only solution I can think of, is that you create your own `Date` implementation (as you don't want to use any "plug-ins"). You could create your own `Date`, which can also store the time-zone, or just has a flag which defines if the `Date` is in `UTC`. If you reconsider the usage of a JavaScript library, you may want to look at, e.g., https://momentjs.com/timezone/.

Here is a sample on how you could get started with your own implementation

```js
function TzDate (date, utc) {
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    this.date = date;
    this.utc = utc ? true : false;
  } else if (typeof date === 'number') {
    this.date = new Date(date);
    this.utc = true;
  } else if (typeof date === 'boolean') {
    this.date = new Date();
    this.utc = date;
  } else {
    this.date = new Date();
    this.utc = utc ? true : false;
  }
}
 
TzDate.prototype = {
  toString: function() {
    return this.isUTC() ? this.date.toUTCString() : this.date.toString()
  },
  
  getTimezoneOffset: function() {
    return this.isUTC() ? 0 : this.date.getTimezoneOffset();
  },

  isUTC: function() {
    return this.utc;
  }
};

console.log(new TzDate().toString());
console.log(new TzDate(true).toString());
console.log(new TzDate(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 8, 10, 0, 0)).toString());
console.log(new TzDate(new Date(2017, 1, 8, 10, 0, 0)).toString());
```

see also:

- [How do I specify the time zone when creating a JavaScript Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/how-do-i-specify-the-time-zone-when-creating-a-javascript-date)
- [date.getTimezoneOffset() is not returning an expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659991/date-gettimezoneoffset-is-not-returning-an-expected-value/33660045)

Comment: I added a little code snippet, which may help you to get started or get an idea what you could do.