# Why does getTimeZoneOffset return a positive number for PST?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, utc

I'm on the Pacific Coast (PST) -8 hours (-420 minutes) from UTC and

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

returns 420. 
Shouldn't it return -420?

I'm trying to calculate a local time to save on the server by passing a local utcoffset. My server is in UTC time

so I wanted to do something like

```
group.DateCreatedLocalTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(viewModel.UtcOffset);
```

but if the time is 420 and not -420 then how will I know to add or subtract minutes from DateTime.UtcNow?

Comment: look at reply of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: so I assume I need to subtract minutes, instead of add minutes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript Date.getTimezoneOffset() consider "-05:00" as a positive offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102435/why-does-javascript-date-gettimezoneoffset-consider-0500-as-a-positive-off)

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript
You can use setMinutes() function.

Example :

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - n);
```

you can subtract this way.