# Inversing sign for timezone offsets with half hour intervals

Tags: javascript

I'm using ideas from [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262840/2545680) to get time zone offset, but [because of standard defined inversion logic for offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102435/why-does-javascript-date-gettimezoneoffset-consider-0500-as-a-positive-off) the code looks like this:

```
  const [, sign, hour, minute] = matchData;
  let result = parseInt(hour) * 60;
  if (sign === '+') result *= -1;
  if (minute) result += parseInt(minute);
```

and for the `Asia/Kolkata` with offset `+5:30` it returns `-270`, which is weird. I'd expect it to be `-1 * (5*60 + 30) = -330`, or even more intuitive not inverted value `5*60 + 30 = 330`, but not `-270`.

Is this the error or is it consistent with the standard?

Comment: Just incase if you missed it, -1 * 5 * 60 + 30 is -270, not -330

Comment: yeah, added paranthesis

Comment: Just swap the two "if" to get -330

Comment: @Astor, so do you think it's an error in the original implementation?

Comment: Yes @MaxKoretskyi, in the code that you posted, you change the sign (*= -1) and after you add the minutes (+30) so you get -270.
If you swap the two lines of the "if"s, you will get -330

Comment: @Astor, yeah, I understand that, just wondering if it was intentional

Comment: No idea about the intention, but the original code does not return the value that you need :)